# Box.com Service Account access

Tags: oauth-2.0, mule, box

All box.com's api's read to require OAuth 2.0 using only Authorization Token grant types. I have a back end system that needs to upload a file to a box.com system. However, I do not understand how a back end system is suppose to integrate, when the authorization flow requires user "approval" to get a token.

Anyone ever done this? I am attempting to integrate a java mule app. I attempted to use the components, but they plain do not work at all, they break the entire anypoint studio. Now I am trying to utilize the http component to make the call but I am losing my patience with it.

please help, I am pretty much ready to drop kick this laptop and live in the woods.

Answer (score 1):

Integration with public online API requires a little study, a little coding, and a little testing. I'm not saying it's easy. Take a look here at a Mule component I've recently created that communicates with Toggl, an online timekeeping service.

https://github.com/ciwise/toggl-api-connector

Your question requires a lot of discussion but it's best answered with example. If Box does not provide a Mule component, you can create one yourself.

The HTTP connector is not going to authenticate or perform any operations at Box for you. The HTTP connector provides the HTTP endpoint (URL entry and browser return). To authenticate your application with Box and call API operations, you'll need to do some work.

This is the high-level recipe for my solution with Toggl service (example)

1. Update your Anypoint Studio with Mule Connector DevKit software
2. Create an Anypoint Connector project in Anypoint Studio (Eclipse)
3. My connector provides multiple methods to process and these are used with different instances of the component (connector) in my use flow.
4. My TogglDataAPIHandler.java makes various checks to see if the application (Mule) is authenticated before making calls to the Application Programming Interface (API). The API is provided by Box so that developers (people writing code) can communicate with the service outside of the web browser. There's no simple answer here. You will have to do some coding. My component/connector is only an example of one way to do this (communicate programmatically with the API).
5. Build and install the connector(component) locally so that we can see it in the Mule Design Palette.
6. Drag as many of our new component (Anypoint connector) as needed into our flow canvas.
7. Test the flow.

I hope that helps. Take a look at my Github repo and Mule Connector. There's a wealth of information in anyone's code. But, integration with an API requires code. You can also search the Exchange for a Box connector. If you find one, then your life is simpler. You still need to read this thoroughly:

https://docs.box.com/docs

Comment: I unfortunately left the company where we were looking into this integration. thank you for putting the time into this answer though!